# Arduino servo control over wi-fi doesn't work

Tags: arduino, android-wifi

Hi I'm using arduino uno and wifi shield. I'm trying to create using the wifi shield to connect to a servo motor through webserver. To be honest I dont really know what im doing. This code is able to control the servo motor once and the whole system is shutdown.
can someone look into my codes and see what is wrong? If can I hope the code is able to control the servo multiple time without stopping.

```
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <WiFi.h>
    #include <Servo.h>

    char ssid[] = "wifi";      //  your network SSID (name)
    char pass[] = "asdfghjkl";   // your network password
    int keyIndex = 0;  
    // your network key Index number (needed only for WEP)
    Servo myservo; 
    int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
    WiFiServer server(80);

    void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);      // initialize serial communication

    myservo.attach(9);

    // check for the presence of the shield:
    if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
    while (true);       // don't continue
    }

    String fv = WiFi.firmwareVersion();
    if (fv != "1.1.0") {
    Serial.println("Please upgrade the firmware");
    }

    // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
    while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to Network named: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);                   // print the network name         (SSID);

    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(1000);
    }
    server.begin();                           // start the web server on port 80
    printWifiStatus();                        // you're connected now, so         print out the status
    }


    void loop() {
    WiFiClient client = server.available();   // listen for incoming clients

    if (client) {                             // if you get a client,
    Serial.println("new client");           // print a message out the serial port
    String currentLine = "";                // make a String to hold incoming data from the client
    while (client.connected()) {            // loop while the client's connected
    if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
    char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
    Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
    if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character

    // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
    // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
    if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
    // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
    // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:
    client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    client.println("Content-type:text/html");
    client.println();

        // the content of the HTTP response follows the header:
    client.print("Click <a href=\"/H\">here</a> turn the Open the door <br>");
    client.print("Click <a href=\"/L\">here</a> turn the Close the door <br>");

    // The HTTP response ends with another blank line:
    client.println();
    // break out of the while loop:
    break;
    } else {    // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine:
    currentLine = "";
    }
    } else if (c != '\r') {  // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
    currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
    }

    // Check to see if the client request was "GET /H" or "GET /L":
    if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /H")) {
    // scale it to use it with the servo (value between 0 and 180)
    myservo.write(800);                  // sets the servo position according to the scaled value
    delay(15);                // GET /H turns the LED on
    }
    if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /L")) {
    // scale it to use it with the servo (value between 0 and 180)
    myservo.write(2500);                  // sets the servo position         according to the scaled value
    delay(15);                  // GET /L turns the LED off
    }
    }
    }

    }
    }

    void printWifiStatus() {
    // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
    Serial.print("SSID: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

    // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
    IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
    Serial.print("IP Address: ");
    Serial.println(ip);

    // print the received signal strength:
    long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
    Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
    Serial.print(rssi);
    Serial.println(" dBm");
    // print where to go in a browser:
    Serial.print("To see this page in action, open a browser to http://");
    Serial.println(ip);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome, please consider making your entire post boldface is essentially not making it bold at all.

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Does the Arduino draw too much power and shut down? Or is this a software issue with it not accepting more requests?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! I dont think is the power issue, most likely is the coding issue. I build this code base on wifi controlling LED in the arduino library.             After i run the coding, the servo motor will activate once then the whole wifi shield will auto turn off. Making me unable to connect to the server. I need to refresh the whole system in order for it to work again.